What’s the most idiomatic word for “a person from another country”?
What’s the most idiomatic word for “a person from another country”? Is it “foreigner”, “alien”, or is there some other way to say it? Let that word be x. If I want to say "I'm a x", which word should I use? Thank you.

Normally you'd say where you're from ("I'm from {country}" or "I'm {nationality}") and "I 'm foreign"  is also a possibility, but if you want a noun, "I'm a foreigner" is better than "I'm an alien".  "Alien" is a legal designation, whereas "foreigner" is cultural.

If you'd been living in the UK for years after having arrived as an immigrant, it's hard to think of any non-facetious contexts where you would say "I'm a foreigner". If it was contextually necessary to say anything with that general sense, I suppose you might say "I wasn't born in this country, you know".

@TimR, what if I want to say “he’s a x”, but I don’t know exactly where he’s from? Is the form “he’s a x (noun)” not idiomatic?

@FumbleFingers, thank you for replying. 1. What’s facetious about “I’m a foreigner”? Can you elaborate? 2. What if the speaker’s not an immigrant? For example, what if he’s just a foreigner in UK? How should he say that?

If you're only in the "foreign" country temporarily, you're probably a tourist. If you intend to be a permanent resident, you probably wouldn't want to advertise your "non-native born" status any more than might be obvious as soon as you open your mouth. Except to make a joke of it. Obviously there's a huge difference between how you might explicitly announce your non-native status (Lord knows why), and how the natives might refer to you as "Not one of us".

@FumbleFingers, 1. But can’t “tourist” mean somebody who’s from your own country? Aren’t you a “tourist” if you’re touring another city in your own country? 2. In some countries there are more than one official language, so you can’t determine if someone’s native as soon as he opens his mouth. 3. For a lot of people, being a foreigner is just a fact. There’s no need to hide it. It comes up in a lot of conversations. It’s very normal. Why do you see it as a joke?

*Foreigner is the right word:".


emigrant meaning.
a person who leaves their own country in order to settle permanently in another.
"she was a Polish emigrant who came to Scotland during the Second World War"
***Foreigner meaning.
a person born in or coming from a country other than one's own.
"the bakery was popular with locals and foreigners alike"



I am a tourist (if just touring). I am an expat

I am a tourist (if just touring though it doesn't imply a foreigner). I am an expat (if working temporarily ). I am an emigrant. (Permanent) Alien (not commonly used)

What about "outlander"?

Ngrams indicates that the occurrence of outlander has greatly increased since the publication of Diana Gabaldon's series of novels, in which it is used to translate the Gaelic Sassenach (which actually means 'English person'). Before that it seems to have been mainly an American word.

outlander is mainly literary in American English and is not in the average speaker's working vocabulary.  If I went into Philadelphia and asked at a bakery, say, or a coffee shop, if many of their customers were outlanders, they would think I was a foreigner.  It's not a word you hear "on the street".

@Kate Bunting, what or who is "Ngrams"?

This useful website.
